# How can I prove this is surjective?

Tags: functions

Let $f: \Bbb{R}- \{2\} \to\Bbb{R} - \{5\}$ be defined by

$$f(x) =\frac{5x + 1}{x-2}$$

My understanding of proving surjections is that you must show $f(x) = y$ i.e that all elements in the domain can be mapped to the co-domain. To do this I tried to substitue $y$ for $x$ such that $f(x) = y$ i.e $x = y+2$, but I am having trouble finding the correct values for $x$ to make $f(x) = y$.  Is this the correct way to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Check what the condition(s) on some $\;w\in\Bbb R\setminus\{5\}\;$ must be to get $\;f(x)=w\;$ for some $\;x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{2\}\;$:

$$\frac{5x+1}{x-2}=w\iff5x+1=xw-2w\iff(5-w)x=-1-2w\iff$$

$$x=\frac{1+2w}{w-5}$$

and the above is defined whenever $\;w-5\neq 0\;$ , so...